# I want to have unique name one to many relationship

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, model-view-controller, one-to-many

I have one to many relationship. Each teether have many colors name
so what I want is to have unique color name for all the teether colors

for example: koala teether have grey and pink color
butterfly teether have pink and white color
so the output of this form is one grey, two pink color, one white.
What I want to have one color name of all the colors. one grey, one pink, one

white[image]

teether.rb

```html
has_many :colors
```

color.rb

```html
belongs_to :teether
```

in teether view

```html
<h4>Colors</h4>
<% @teethers.each do |t| %>
  <% for item in t.colors.pluck(:name).uniq %>
    <li>
      <button class="btn"  onclick="filterSelection('<%= item %>')"><span class= "<%= item %>"></span><p class="red"><%= item %></p></button>
    </li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And also it duplicate the teether when I add new color to the same one

```html
<% @teethers.each do |t| %>
  <% if t.colors.exists? %>
    <% t.colors.pluck(:name).uniq.each do |item| %>
      <div class="column <%= item %><%= t.status %> <%= t.gender %>">

        <div class="col_1_of_3 span_1_of_3"> 
          <div class="inner_content clearfix">
            <div class="product_image">
              <%= link_to t do %>
                <%= image_tag t.image.url , style: "width:100%"%>
              <% end %>
            </div>
            <% if t.status == 'New' %>
              <div class="sale-box">
                <span class="on_sale title_shop">New</span>
              </div> 
            <% end %>
            <% if t.status == 'Sale' %>
              <div class="sale-box1">
                <span class="on_sale title_shop">Sale</span>
              </div> 
            <% end %>
            <% if t.status == 'Sold Out' %>
              <div class="sale-box">
                <span class="sold title_shop">Sold Out</span>
              </div> 
            <% end %>
            <div class="price">
              <div class="cart-left">
                <p class="title"><%= link_to t.name,t %></p>
                <div class="price1">
                  <% for item in t.colors.pluck(:name).uniq %>
                    <%= item %>
                  <% end %>
                  <span class="actual">$<%= t.price %></span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="cart-right"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Here is teether controller

```html
  def index
    @teethers= Teether.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
    if params[:search]
      @search_term = params[:search]
      @teethers= @teethers.search_by(@search_term)
    end
  end
```

You will understand more when you check the picture
Please help me to solve the duplicate of the color name 
and also the duplicate of the teether information when I add new color
Thank you in advance

Comment: maybe this can help you https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness @nour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your in `@teether` loop, Next your looping `t.colors.pluck(:name).uniq`. This means you making unique for each `teether` so there will be duplication on display. You need to take one empty array and push all `teether` colors into array, then apply uniq for that array. Now you can apply that array into your COLORS area display. From controller you can send colors array variable to view. Try below code.

```
@colors = Array.new
@teethers.each {|t| @colors << t.colors.pluck(:name) }
```

Now in view you can use @colors.uniq

```
<h4>Colors</h4>
<% @colors.flatten.uniq.each do |item| %>
  <li>
  <button class="btn"  onclick="filterSelection('<%= item %>')"><span class= "<%= 
  item %>"></span><p class="red"><%= item %></p></button>
</li>
<% end %>
```

Try this , if you need any queries then lemme know.

Comment: Thank you. Each color have a name. How to include that in the answer? I tried this <%= item.name%> but it give me just "Color"

Comment: I have updated my answer please check. Use `@teethers.each {|t| t.colors.each {|c| @colors << c.name } }` in controller or for better you can use `@teethers.each {|t| @colors << t.colors.pluck(:name) }` also.

Comment: If you use `@teethers.each {|t| @colors << t.colors.pluck(:name) }` then you need to use `flatten` as i mentioned above in view

Comment: Awesome the color thing fixed :) Thanks and how about the other issue duplicating the images? <% @teethers.each do |t| %>
                  <% if t.colors.exists? %>
                  <% t.colors.pluck(:name).uniq.each do |item| %><%= link_to t do %>
                          <%= image_tag t.image.url() , style: "width:100%"%>
                        <% end %>

Comment: Glad to help you. Please accept my answer of it is works

Comment: I will accept it for sure but can you check the other issue that I mentioned it in my question please! Thanks

Comment: Your displaying images in colors loop , so how many colors you have ,that number of image duplicates your getting. So please place image_tag in first loop `@teethers.each` loop.

Comment: You have to use colors loop for only displaying colors , after that end the colors loop.

Comment: I know I am using it for the color filter. ex: when you press the pink color. all the pink teethers information will show <div class="column <%= t.colors.name %><%= t.status %> <%= t.gender %>">

Comment: <div class="column  <% t.colors.each do |item| %>><%= item.name %><% end %><%= t.status %> <%= t.gender %>">